# All newlines are removed when saving cat output into a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ash

I have the following file

```
linux$ cat test.txt
toto
titi
tete
tata
```

Saving the cat output into a variable will discard the newlines

```
linux$ msgs=`cat test.txt`
linux$ echo $msgs
toto titi tete tata
```

How to keep the output containing the newlines in the variables?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The shell is splitting the `msgs` variable so `echo` get multiple parameters.
You need to quote your variable to prevent this to happen:

```
echo "$msgs"
```

Comment: Confusing yet simple. Bash in a nut-shell

Answer (score 1):

I had this:

```
echo $(cat myfile.sh) >> destination.sh
```

that was causing the problem, so I changed it to:

```
cat myfile.sh >> destination.sh
```

and that worked, lulz

Comment: why is the first one, the subbash removes newlines, i dont get it

Comment: i found out why, it's because  of the IFS, internal field separator, save it, set to blank , and restore it

Answer (score -6):

you can use the redirection "|"

```
echo | cat test.txt
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question nor make sense. `cat` ignores its standard input when passed file name(s) as argument.